# Map not loading - Greyed Screen when trying to load Google Maps API for Web

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

Instead of seeing the map, all I see is a grey screen with the google signature below it.

I followed the instructions on this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#Audience

Also, I have created and assigned a **server key** to my index.php page as required.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Edited:

```
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
      center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
      zoom: 8
    });
  }


function loadScript()
 {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?   
      key=AIzaSyAfUAdasdaoBE9PzjWRJ3MRlcSaYh0&callback=initMap";

   document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

   window.onload = loadScript;
 </script>

.
.
.

<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
```

Comment: Please show your code...

Answer (score 0):

If I copy/paste your code in a new html file, the only error I get is a weird space in the Google Maps url. When I suppress it, it works :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var map;
            function initMap() {
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('googleMap'), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                });
            }


            function loadScript()
            {
                var script = document.createElement("script");
                script.type = "text/javascript";
                script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAfUA7aWeXe4fxoBE9PzjWRJ3MRlcSaYh0&callback=initMap";
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }

            window.onload = loadScript;
        </script>
        <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Copied it too (to sublime) to try to see but I don't have any spaces.

Comment: Yes, same results.

Comment: Ok, so please tell if you have an error in the javascript console of your browser ?

Comment: I found the source of the problem, it's the CDN of bootstrap.

Comment: I found the source of the problem, it's the CDN of bootstrap. If I remove them then problem is solved

Comment: scandal thanks for your help, I'll post another question about the integration between bootstrap to google maps.